# Should I dealloc a nonnull property; and if so, how?

Tags: objective-c, swift

*I'm exposing a few properties from an Objective-C project to Swift (based on [this repo](https://github.com/lxmmxl56/iPhone-libmecab)), but have no experience in Objective-C, so I'm rather out of my depth here, so please bear with me.*

I'm wondering **how to correctly dealloc a `nonnull` property** (or whether it's necessary at all!). I've provisionally dealloc'ed the `nonnull` property `surface` by setting it to `null` (in the same manner as is done for the `nullable` `partOfSpeech`). However, this prompts the following warning:

> Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

... so I wonder whether it's redundant. Is there anything I should do instead to handle my `nonnull` property, during the `Node` class's `dealloc` block?

Given the interface, `node.h`:

```
@interface Node : NSObject {
    NSString *surface;
    NSString *partOfSpeech;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain, nonnull) NSString *surface;
@property (nonatomic, retain, nullable) NSString *partOfSpeech;

- (nullable NSString *)partOfSpeech;

@end
```

... And the implementation, `node.m`:

```
@implementation Node

@synthesize surface;
@synthesize partOfSpeech;

// surface is assumed to be set post-initialisation.

- (void)setPartOfSpeech:(NSString *)value {
    if (partOfSpeech) [partOfSpeech release];
    partOfSpeech = value ? [value retain] : nil;
}

- (NSString *)partOfSpeech {
    if (!features || [features count] < 1) return nil;
    return [features objectAtIndex:0];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // WARNING: "Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument"
    self.surface = nil;
    self.partOfSpeech = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

... And given that a `Node`'s lifecycle is like this:

```
    Node *newNode = [Node new];
    newNode.surface = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:node->surface length:node->length encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
   // ... Do stuff with newNode (eg. add to array of Node)...
    [newNode release];
```

Comment: @Ron Thanks for pointing that out. It's an Obj-C wrapper for a C++ project, (which ultimately exposes headers to Swift!), so I got mixed up. As you say, the code presented here is purely Obj-C.

Comment: Is there a special reason for not using ARC (automatic reference counting)?

Comment: @MartinR As this is a wrapper for a high-performance, industry-standard tokeniser, there is possibly some argument for tight, explicit control over the memory management. But I think, in practice, Xcode overrides the memory management to use ARC anyway (if I've understood correctly). As for my 'special reason', I'd say, if nothing more, "as a learning exercise".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First:* The compiler can automatically synthesize instance variables and
setters/getters for your properties. So your interface should be just

```
// Node.h
@interface Node : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain, nonnull) NSString *surface;
@property (nonatomic, retain, nullable) NSString *partOfSpeech;

@end
```

and no `@synthesize` statements are needed in the implementation file.
The compiler will automatically create instance variables
`_surface` and `_partOfSpeech`, and also create accessor methods

```
- (NSString *) surface;
- (void)setSurface:(NSString *)value;
- (NSString *)partOfSpeech;
- (void)setPartOfSpeech:(NSString *)value;
```

which do "the right thing", with or without ARC. You can override
those methods if you want to implement some custom logic, but you don't have to implement a standard setter like your `setPartOfSpeech`.

If you use ARC (automatic reference counting) then that is all,
nothing more is needed. And
I would really recommend to do so. The compiler inserts the required retain/release calls at compile time, and is quite clever in avoiding
unnecessary calls. See for example

- [Confirmed: Objective-C ARC is slow. Don’t use it! (sarcasm off)](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2013/03/confirmed-arc-slow/)

about some comparisons. With MRC (manual reference counting), your code might even be slower, or
have memory leaks.

*But to answer your question:* With MRC you have to release the
instance variables in `dealloc`

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [_surface release];
    [_partOfSpeech release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

as explained in [Memory Management Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) in the "Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide".

You should *not* use the accessor methods in `dealloc` as in your

```
self.surface = nil;
self.partOfSpeech = nil;
```

see [Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html).

Comment: I think in your last para you meant you should not use *accessor methods* as your reference states.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using manual memory management you can just `release` the object stored in the properties backing variable. As you've named the backing variable the same as the property use the `->` to clearly reference the backing variable:

```
[self->surface release];
```

Or if you want to do this with assignment just assign the empty string literal:

```
self.surface = @"";
```

The string literal is created at compile time, lives throughout the program execution, and takes up very little space. The assignment will caused the `release` (and deallocation if the reference count reaches zero) of the previous value in the property, just like assigning `nil` (or any other value).

HTH

Comment: Where would either of those code snippets go? Would they go in place of where I've currently put `self.surface = nil;`?